# WTRN0062E: An illegal attempt to use multiple resources that have only one-phase capability has occurred within a global transaction

Tags: java, transactions, db2, websphere-8

In webspehere App Server(WAS)version 8,getting the below error with Non-XA datasource.I have changed to XA datasource to test but giving different error as connection timeout/not available.Below is the error for Non-XA Datasource:

RegisteredRes E   WTRN0062E: An illegal attempt to use multiple resources that have only one-phase capability has occurred within a global transaction.
LocalTransact E   J2CA0030E: Method enlist caught com.ibm.ws.Transaction.IllegalResourceIn2PCTransactionException: Illegal attempt to enlist multiple 1PC XAResources
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:870)

Interesting part is it is working fine in WAS6.Really appreciate if anyone can suggest something?

Comment: Do I need to enable Last Participant Support (LPS) Servers ->Application Servers ->Cpntainers ->Transaction ->Addition Properties ->Custom properties ->ACCEPT_HEURISTIC_HAZARD in the Name field and type TRUE
in the Value field. Will it work?

Answer (score 5):

This error is indicating that you are using at least two transactional resources (databases,queues, SAP managed connections,... ) inside a global transaction. 
Within a globlal transaction, all resources must support Two Phase Commits (or at least, all except one, if last participant support is enabled)

If you are using QueueConnectionFactories, there are a checkbox to enable XA. Regarding datasources, you should use the XA driver and so on.

I would double check all the resources to assure all of them are configured to support 2PC.

Regards